# How to INSERT NULL using Ruby mysql2?

Tags: mysql, ruby, null, mariadb

How can I insert NULLs in MySQL/MariaDB fields, using the Ruby 'mysql2' module?

I'm using a prepared statement and a Ruby Array. When the initialized fields in the Array are the default `nil`, I get a runtime exception. When I initialize the fields to 'NULL', the literal string 'NULL' is inserted, rather than the unique NULL value.

```
msgs.each do |msg|
…
        # args: Array of information that will be fed to MariaDB.
        # 0:record_type
        # 1:IP_source
        # 2:IP_dest
        # 3:port_source
        # 4:port_dest
        # 5:MAC
        # 6:record_type_arg
        # 7:Date
        # 8:full_entry
        # 9:IP_source_name
        # 10:IP_dest_name
        # 11:abuse_email
        args = Array.new(12, 'NULL')
        args[0] = recType = recType.rstrip
        args[7] = recDate.to_s
        args[8] = full_entry
        #
        # For each distinct log record type, parse the record and stuff the SQL arg Array.
        #
        case recType
            when /Access Control/
…
        statement = client.prepare("
            INSERT INTO a_router_log
                (`record_type`, `IP_source`, `IP_dest`, `port_source`, `port_dest`, `MAC`, `record_type_arg`, `Date`, `full_entry`, `IP_source_name`, `IP_dest_name`, `abuse_email`)
                VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")
        statement.execute(args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4], args[5], args[6], args[7], args[8], args[9], args[10], args[11])
    end
```

I'm pretty sure it isn't a database issue, as I can do things like `` UPDATE a_router_log SET `IP_source` = NULL WHERE `IP_source` = "NULL" ``, which then "fixes" the fields that had the 'NULL' string in them.

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Comment: Did you try to set the value to `nil` instead of the string `'NULL'`?

Comment: This sounds like it's working exactly as expected. How else would you be able to insert a string `"NULL"`, if not by entering those characters as a string? If you want to insert `NULL` (not a string), then use `nil`.

Comment: Based on both of your suggestions, I will try the Ruby default ```nil``` again. But I have tried it, and ended up with a runtime error deep in the mysql2 library, because MariaDB did not know what to do with ```nil```.

Comment: Sheesh. Must have been some sort of cockpit error. I swore that it wouldn't work with ```nil```, throwing some MySQL error, but I just did a test case, and ```nil``` Array entries DOES put ```NULL``` in a column. So I'll change the script to ```args = Array.new(12)``` and wait for cron to fire it off early tomorrow. If @spikermann or @Tom Lord writes this as an answer, I'll mark it answered.